# CSS is not reflecting on button inside <dl>

Tags: css

Can someone tell me what I am missing on the following code? Why css is not being reflected on  the button inside the "dl" and "dd" tags?

HTML

```
<dl class="zend_form">
    <dd><button value="" name="submit" type="submit">Sign In</button></dd>
</dl>
```

CSS

```
.zend_form dd input[type="submit"]{
    background:red;
    }
```

JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/2RYyD/302/

Comment: Because you're targeting an `input` when it's a `button`?

Comment: A button is not an input, a button is a button and an input is an input.  See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2RYyD/303/

Answer (score 6):

You should instead be using a `button` selector not an `input` based on your HTML

```
.zend_form dd button[type="submit"] {}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2RYyD/304/